# Valgrind reporting conditional jump or move in main

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

I need some help determining what is wrong with my code:

I have a struct

```
struct structName{
    //members
} *pointerToStruct, *tail;
```

Then in main I get user input and call a function to create the node.

```
struct structName* createNewNode(int x){
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)calloc(3,sizeof(struct Node));
    if (newNode == NULL){
        perror("Calloc Failed... exiting\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    newNode->digit = x;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

Then another function takes care of linking things together:

```
if(pointerToStruct == NULL) {
    pointerToStruct = newNode; //where newNode is the node created in the above function
    tail = newNode;
    return;
}
pointerToStruct->prev = newNode;
newNode->next = pointerToStruct;
pointerToStruct = newNode;
```

Valgrind complains about a *Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s). at memLocation: main(location of file)*

What I find really odd is that it is reporting this error in main before I ever ask for user input, before a node is ever created. It gets flagged right away.

Comment: Is this actually where in the file Valgrind is pointing? Because you should include **that** into your question.

Comment: No it gives me a memory location but I'm not really sure what to make of it. And I imagine it changes every time I run it, 0x400B41

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene updated, please see the post now

Comment: Well... Your `insert` function allocated memory... And if it can't assign `numOne` to  point to it, immediately leaks it... I think it's obvious why Valgrind would complain.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry missed part of the code when creating an example. Please see the updated post. I'm not worried about freeing the memory, the error happens regardless.

Comment: @frillybob What's the error message?

Comment: Why do you allocate 3 structures when you only use one (with `struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)calloc(3,sizeof(struct Node));`)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I allocated 3 structures because of the 2 pointers and the one int. This is not the source of the problem, malloc produces the same result - which doesn't require the number of structures.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-g` (debug) option?  If not, you're missing the information Valgrind will give you about line numbers.

Comment: @melpomene returning 1 isn't the source of the error, I fixed that. The error, given by valgrind, (the program runs just fine) is Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s). at (a memory location): main(location of file)

Comment: I agree the allocating in triplicate isn't the cause of your trouble, but it is a waste of memory.  Your justification is specious: `sizeof(struct Node)` is the size of a complete `struct Node`.

Comment: @frillybob No, what's the actual, complete valgrind output?

Comment: @melpomene I used Johnathn Leffler suggestion to compile with -g. It gave me the exact line number and I was able to solve my problem. It had nothing to do with the structs or memory management. Not sure what valgrind was going on about but it's solved now. Thanks!